# How to pass all key value pairs of a hashmap into a function (without passing the whole hashmap)?

Tags: clojure, hashmap

I want to pass in all the key-val pairs of a hashmap into a function, but not the whole hashmap.

So I have a function I can't change that looks something like this:

```
(defn foo [a b c & {:keys [x y z]}]
  (println x y z))
```

I have a hashmap that will have a variable amount of keys and values. Let's say one instance will be:

```
(def bar {:d 1
          :e 2
          :x "x"
          :y "y"})
```

How do I call pass in all the key-value pairs into foo without passing the whole hashmap?
I want to do

```
(foo "a" "b" "c" 
     :d 1
     :e 2
     :x "x"
     :y "y")
```

Comment: I think there's a typo in the last code block, I believe it should be `(foo "a" "b" "c" :x "x" :y "y")`

Comment: You can construct a sequence of arguments with `concat` and then `apply` your function `foo` to it: `(apply foo (apply concat "a" "b" "c" bar))`

Comment: @A.Webb Holy shit, that works! That's amazing, thank you!

Comment: @SteffanWestcott Negative. The & {:keys [x y z]} in foo should ignore :d and :e. I just wanted to show the variability of the map I will be working with, but thanks for checking!

Comment: This is a recent addition to clojure.core that looks related: https://clojure.org/news/2021/03/18/apis-serving-people-and-programs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`select-keys` can be used to prune a map to desired keys:

```clj
(apply foo "a" "b" "c" (apply concat (select-keys bar [:x :y :z])))
```

Alternatively, a cheeky workaround is to use Clojure `1.11.0-alpha1` or later which [supports keyword arguments to be passed as maps](https://clojure.org/news/2021/03/18/apis-serving-people-and-programs). With this you can simply do:

```clj
(foo "a" "b" "c" bar)
```

Comment: `(apply concat (select-keys bar [:x :y :z]))` could also be `(mapcat #(find bar %) [:x :y :z])`

Answer (score 0):

If that `foo` is something you "inherited", then one way would be:

```
(apply foo "a" "b" "c" (into [] cat bar))
```

This "flattens" the key-values and apply calls just that.

If you rather only pass what is needed you can use `select-keys` on
`bar` first.

If `foo` is something you have written yourself, reconsider.  This
pattern feels nice for human consumption at first glance, but it becomes
hard to just pass in the map.  So my suggestion would be: just allow
a map to be passed as fourth argument.  If the map is optional there,
provide another arity version of `foo`, that passes an empty map.

Comment: Unfortunately foo is not something I wrote and needs to stay like that for backwards compatibility. Passing a map in would have been WAY better design! Oh well.